# Change the font of an entire document without affecting formatting using Google Docs API

Tags: python, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am trying to change the font of an entire Google Doc using the API. The purpose is to let users of our application export documents with their company’s font.

This is what I am currently doing:

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

doc_service = build("docs", "v1")
document = self.doc_service.documents().get(documentId="[Document ID]").execute()
requests = []
for element in document["body"]["content"]:
    if "sectionBreak" in element:
        continue  # Trying to change the font of a section break causes an error
    requests.append(
        {
            "updateTextStyle": {
                "range": {
                    "startIndex": element["startIndex"],
                    "endIndex": element["endIndex"],
                },
                "textStyle": {
                    "weightedFontFamily": {
                        "fontFamily": "[Font name]"
                    },
                },
                "fields": "weightedFontFamily",
            }
        }
    )
doc_service.documents().batchUpdate(
    documentId=self.copy_id, body={"requests": requests}
).execute()
```

The code above changes the font, but it also removes any bold text formatting because it overrides the entire style of an element. Some options I have looked into:

## `DocumentStyle`

Documents have a [`DocumentStyle`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#DocumentStyle) property, but it does not contain any font information.

## `NamedStyles`

Documents also have a [`NamedStyles`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#NamedStyles) property. It contains styles like `NORMAL_TEXT` and `HEADING_1`. I could loop through all these and change their `textStyle.weightedFontFamily`. This would be the ideal solution, because it would keep style information where it belongs. But I have not found a way to change `NamedStyles` using the API.

## Deeper loop

I could continue with my current approach, looping through the `elements` list on each `element`, keeping everything but the font from `textStyle` (which contains things like `bold: true`). However, our current approach already takes too long to execute, and such an approach would be both slower and more brittle, so I would like to avoid this.

Comment: when you say export, it is exported in what format ?

Comment: Either Google Docs (copied and shared with the user), PDF (downloaded) or DOCX (downloaded).

Comment: Why not create a new document using the old one / with modified fontSize ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Extract the `textStyle` out of the current element and only change/add the `weightedFontFamily/fontFamily` object.*

#### Code Example:

```
for element in document["body"]["content"]:
    if "sectionBreak" in element:
        continue  # Trying to change the font of a section break causes an error

    textStyle = element["paragraph"]["elements"][0]["textStyle"]
    textStyle["weightedFontFamily"]["fontFamily"] = "[Font name]"

    requests.append(
        {
            "updateTextStyle": {
                "range": {
                    "startIndex": element["startIndex"],
                    "endIndex": element["endIndex"],
                },
                "textStyle": textStyle,
                "fields": "weightedFontFamily",
            }
        }
    )
doc_service.documents().batchUpdate(
    documentId=self.copy_id, body={"requests": requests}
).execute()
```

Comment: Thanks! Because of the performance implications I mentioned, I’d prefer not to do it this way.

Comment: The `batchUpdate` method will *overwrite* your current settings and not append them, regardless of what you're updating - it uses HTTP `POST` and is handled as such, rather than using `PATCH`. Unfortunately this is the only way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me, even with section breaks in between, and at the end of the document. You might want to explore more corner cases..

This basically tries to mimic the `SelectAll` option

```
document = service.documents().get(documentId=doc_id).execute()
endIndex = sorted(document["body"]["content"], key=lambda x: x["endIndex"], reverse=True,)[0]["endIndex"]
service.documents().batchUpdate(
    documentId=doc_id,
    body={
        "requests": {
            "updateTextStyle": {
                "range": {
                    "endIndex": endIndex,
                    "startIndex": 1,
                },
                "fields": "fontSize",
                "textStyle": {"fontSize": {"magnitude": 100, "unit": "pt"}},
            }
        }
    },
).execute()
```

Same should work for other fields too.

However, if you are going to just share a docx file to all the clients, you could keep a local copy of the PDF / DOCX and then modify those. It is fairly easy to work around the styles in DOCX (it is a bunch of xml files)

Use this to explore and update DOCX files [OOXML Tools Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ooxml-tools/bjmmjfdegplhkefakjkccocjanekbapn?hl=en)

Similarly PDFs are key-values pairs stored as records. Check this:  [ReportLab](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/src/default/)